# How to check what application uses my services - arcgis server 9.3

Tags: arcgis-server, log

I serve a lot of map services via my arcgis server 9.3. Can I determine somehow which webapplication or desktop clients are using or were using my services? I know that I can view apache access log and by this way execute this task, but I think that it is not most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility available on ArcScripts - [ServiceMonitor](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15335) - which can let you get at least some monitoring on your services. I have not tested it myself though.

Free apps are Apache JMeter and Fiddler.

Commercial apps are [GeoCortex](http://www.geocortex.com/arcgis-server-software/geocortex-optimizer/) and [GeoXMF](http://www.geoxmf.com/geoxmfweb2/pages/alerter/alerter.htm) (tested myself, has support for 9.3).

Comment: thank you for answer I didn't know about ServiceMonitor. But can you say something more about using JMeter? I alwas thought, that this software is only for performance test of application/web-server, and not for logging..

Comment: I am not sure if JMeter does have the ability to log incoming requests (say IP address and type of application), but I thought to share the link since it has similar purposes and maybe there could be some additional modules for you. I assume it might be easier to find a piece of software that works on the OS level, tracing incoming requests - like IIS Log Analyzer (http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/iis-log-analyzer).